# Creating a dynamic 2d array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have to create variable length sequences from a column along its rows.

Eg- Suppose the column is as below

> 2 
> 4 
> 3

I want to create a sequence like this

> 2 | 1 | 2 
> 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
> 3 | 1 | 2 | 3

I'm able to create a single sequence using the SEQUENCE function but to spread it over the entire column, I'm not able to use the ARRAYFORMULA correctly.

If I write `ARRAYFORMULA(SEQUENCE(A1:A3))`, it gives me a column of three ones.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a matrix like this:

`=arrayformula( if( sequence(1, max(A1:A)) <= A1:A, sequence(1, max(A1:A)), iferror(1/0) ) )`

The formula uses the open-ended reference `A1:A`, and will thus process all rows in column `A`. If you want to limit the formula to a predefined number of rows, use a bounded reference like `A1:A42`.

To limit the formula to the continuous rows where column `A` contains a number, use `filter()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( if( sequence(1, max(A1:A)) <= filter(A1:A, isnumber(A1:A)), sequence(1, max(A1:A)), iferror(1/0) ) )`

To limit the formula to the last row that contains a number, use the `max(row() * isnumber())` pattern, like this:

`=arrayformula( if( sequence(1, max(A1:A)) <= filter(A1:A, row(A1:A) <= max(row(A1:A) * isnumber(A1:A))), sequence(1, max(A1:A)), iferror(1/0) ) )`

A suggested edit proposed to use `indirect()` for the same purpose. `indirect()` is a volatile function that gets recalculated *every* time *any* value in the spreadsheet is edited. It thus hurts spreadsheet performance and is best avoided.

Comment: Could you explain the formula? I'm wrapping my head around it for some time but to no avail.

Comment: An [arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093275) wrapper lets you evaluate a formula over a range of cells rather than a single cell, returning multiple results automatically. Also see [if()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093364), [sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244), [max()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094013), [iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304).

Comment: Can you explain the working of arrayformula in this. Like for a single row it will check if each value is less than the max value, if it is, a sequence should start from there right? So accordingly each row should be filled with only ones I guess

Comment: See the [ArrayFormula lab](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/01/16/arrayformula-lab/) blog post by Maxim Makhrov.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding; why wouldn't `sequence(1, max(A1:A))` just work on it's own but wrapping it in an IF function would?

Comment: Well... `sequence()` does work on its own. The problem is that it creates a single row of values rather than a matrix as you wanted. The solution is to use `if()` to repeat the row multiple times, each time only taking the values that are less than or equal to the value in column `A` in that row. An `arrayformula()` wrapper is needed to evaluate the formula over a range of cells.

Comment: I know I can accept the answer. I just wanted to understand the working of the formula before accepting it. Tension not I will accept it and I remember that

Comment: Can you explain why `=ArrayFormula(IF(SEQUENCE(1,4) <= 3, SEQUENCE(1,4),""))` will product 1,2,3 as output and not 1,1,1

Comment: The formula returns four values: 1, 2, 3, "". During the first three `if()` iterations the condition is true, and it returns the value that appears in the same position in the array produced by the second parameter as the test iteration. In the fourth iteration the condition is false, and it returns the third parameter. There is no array in the third parameter, so the same value gets returned regardless of position.

Comment: I think we could work without the iferror(1/0) in 3rd parameter, it could be left empty, like IF(cond., if true, )

Comment: That is correct. I prefer explicitly writing out the `iferror(1/0)` pattern because it makes it clearly visible that a truly blank value is being returned.

Comment: Could you answer this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164746/295868), no one's answered it till now