# Sorting multiple columns using formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Give a sequence of columns, I want to sort each column individually using formula because of some reason.

Eg.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 8 | 1 | 3 |
|  | 9 | 3 | 4 |
|  | 7 |  | 4 |

Expected output

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 7 | 2 | 4 |
|  | 8 | 3 | 4 |
|  | 9 |  | 5 |

Is there any way to do that with a formula? Also the formula should take the whole range as input like A1:D4. Any help is appreciated

**Edit** - My real problem is solving a trick question, it is not related to any real-world dataset. I saw this trick question answered on youtube here - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxHTeaxFWKk&ab_channel=LearnGoogleSpreadsheets). While the solution is provided for a single cell and dragged for remaining cells, I wanted to implement it using ArrayFormula for the whole column so that I don't have to keep dragging it again.

I don't know if it is possible or not, or is it valid to solve questions like these in google sheets. Do tell if it's not appropriate in tools like sheets.

Comment: Hmm... is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: @doubleunary: sorry for the late response, my work immediately changed from sheets to other things. Yes it as an XY problem, actually problem was sort a number like - 7865 to 5678, I have the formula for a single cell but I wanted to expand it to the whole column that's why I was trying various things, this is the video I referred to for a single cell sort - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxHTeaxFWKk&ab_channel=LearnGoogleSpreadsheets)

Comment: Please edit the question so that it tells what your end goal is. Show _realistic-looking_ source data and also show your _expected results_.

Comment: @doubleunary, I've added my real aim, although it is not for any real world dataset but a trick question instead

Comment: I prefer to use my time helping people with real-world problems. It sounds like you are trying to solve this for fun. You will get more fun out of the problem if you solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this formula should solve:

```
={SORT(A1:A,1,true),SORT(B1:B,1,true),SORT(C1:C,1,true),SORT(D1:D,1,true)}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
this formula is based on your last request:

```
=byrow(A1:A,lambda(r,if(r="",,join("",sort(transpose(split(regexreplace(r&"","(?s)(.{1})","$1 ")," ")))))))
```

all the strings (number and/or text) contained in the cells of `column A` will be sorted individually

Comment: Yeah but I want something that takes the whole range as input like A2:D5, could you make it like that?

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: are you sure this works? It didn't work for me. Also, I am trying to give the whole range as input i.e. all columns at once.